# riotjs rendering nested tags rows outside of table

Tags: javascript, html, riot.js

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5ytp918/3/).

There is a parent `<table>` html tag and nested custom riot tag to build up the row.

On inspecting the generated mark-up the test rows are rendered **outside** of the table.

If I use nested `<div />`s in this way, it renders as I expect - children of the elements.  Is this by design? Or a quirk of the way rendering works internally with html tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug to me, even if you use the latest riot version `2.4.1`, your `testrow` is not rendered in the `table`-element.

If you wrap the `testrow` in a `div`

```
<div>
  <testrow></testrow>
</div>
```

...it is rendered as it should:

```
<div>
  <testrow><tr> <td>1</td> </tr></testrow>
</div>
```

I would suggest to open a new [issue](https://github.com/riot/riot/issues).

#### Update

No *quirk*, your rendered result would just be invalid markup. Riot `2.3.17` introduced a new [`data-is`](http://riotjs.com/guide/#html-elements-as-tags)-attribute, which could resolve your [issue](https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/1760):

```
<table>
  <tbody data-is="testrow"></tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v5ytp918/4/

#### Extra-Tip

To check your markup for validity/correctness, just wrap your riot-tag in a `template`-tag and inspect its `innerHTML`:

https://jsfiddle.net/aebo6zpg/

Comment: Indeed it does.  I raise the issue anyway and go forth with the `data-is` attribute - thanks for clarification.

Comment: @PhilCooper Good to hear, that it helps. Also, see my last update about validity... :)

Answer (score 0):

> If I use nested s in this way, it renders as I expect - children of the elements. Is this by design? Or a quirk of the way rendering works internally with html tables?

Cost me also two hours recently. The root cause of the problem is that 'table' is special in that it defines its own [formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/tables.html#q17.0), and a TR can't exist outside of that.
While riot thinks components and builds their virtual DOM without dependencies (except the ones explicitly declared by the user).
[This](https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/236#issuecomment-71771721) illustrates the problem:

```
> let el = document.createElement('div')
> el.innerHTML = "<tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>"
> el.innerHTML
"foobar"
```

=> You can't render a TR standalone.

I did not stumble over any such problem, btw, this is the only one you have to deal with workarounds(?) as given by yckart already.
An [alternative solution](https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/168#issuecomment-95789262) would be to use CSS btw, let CSS render a nested div structure visually into a table:

`You can also use CSS to emulate tables if you need to.
display: table
display: table-row
display: table-cell`